# Sending an object from html select option to controller using thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'd like to send an object from a select to my controller using thymeleaf. This is the model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Skills")
@Builder
public class Skill {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 40)
        private String title;

        @Column(name = "category", nullable = false, length = 30)
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private Category category;
}
```

I'm adding a list of skills to the view

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class IndexController {

        private final SkillService skillService;

        @GetMapping("/manager-profile")
        public String managerProfile(Model model) {
                model.addAttribute("skillList", skillService.findAllSkills());
                return "manager-profile";
        }
}
```

In the view itself I iterate through the list and create the options from there.

```
        <form th:action="@{/getEmployeeBySkill}" method="post" id="skill-form">
            <div class="select-box manager">
                <select class="select_box manager" id="select-skill" name="skill">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option th:each="skill : ${skillList}" th:attr="data-category=${skill.category}" th:value="${skill}" th:name="skill" th:text="${skill.title}"></option>
                </select>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="experience" placeholder="Experience">
                <button type="submit" class="btn manager-select_box">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Based on the selection that is made I'd like to send the skill object back to another controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class EmployeeController {

        private final EmployeeService employeeService;

        @PostMapping("/getEmployeeBySkill")
        String getEmployeesBySkill (Model model, @ModelAttribute("skill") Skill skill) {
                // do stuff
                return "candidate-list";
        }

}
```

However, I'm getting the error message

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.neusta.domain.Skill'; Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'com.neusta.domain.Skill@bb0c873'
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.neusta.domain.Skill'; Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'com.neusta.domain.Skill@bb0c873'
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to "send an object" via Thymeleaf (or HTML for the matter).

The problem is the attibute `th:value="${skill}"`. If you look at the generated HTML ("View source" of the page in the browser), or look at the end of the error message, you'll see that the attibute value is `com.neusta.domain.Skill@bb0c873` (or simular). That is the default result of the `toString()` method of a class, which is used to render `${skill}`, because a HTML attribute can't hold an object, but just a string, and that is the only String representation the system knows of. And this String representation can't be "converted" back to an object.

If you read the error message, you'll notice Spring ist attempting to convert that value into a `Long`. That is because it is expecting a String representation that it **can** convert back to a `Skill` entity instance, namely the database ID, which is a `Long`, so the attribute should be: `th:value="${skill.id}"`